# Ruby script to extract numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, numbers, extract

I have a .txt file with characters that look like this:

```
7  3  5  7  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  6  7  5  5 22 1 4 23 16 18 5  13 34 24 17 50 30 42 35 29 27 52 35 44 52 36 39 25 40 50 52 40 2 52 52 31 35 30 19 32 46 50 43 36 15 21 16 36 25 7  3  5  17  3  3  3  3  23  3  3  46 1 2
```

I want to extract numbers >10 only if 7 or more of the next 15 numbers are greater than 10 too.

In this case, I would have the output:

```
22 1 4 23 16 18 5  13 34 24 17 50 30 42 35 29 27 52 35 44 52 36 39 25 40 50 52 40 2 52 52 31 35 30 19 32 46 50 43 36 15 21 16 36 25
```

Note that in this output there's numbers <10, but they pass the condition of having 7 or more of the next 15 numbers >10.

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: try `scan` with a regex to extract the numbers, and `each_cons` to get groups of 16, and `select` to count the numbers > 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a homework question, but I'll give you an attempted answer just for fun anyway.

```
numbers = "7  3  5  7  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  6  7  5  5 22 1 4 23 16 18 5  13 34 24 17 50 30 42 35 29 27 52 35 44 52 36 39 25 40 50 52 40 2 52 52 31 35 30 19 32 46 50 43 36 15 21 16 36 25 7  3  5  17  3  3  3  3  23  3  3  46 1 2"
numbers.split.each_cons(16).map{|x| x[0] if x[1..15].count{|y| y.to_i > 10} >= 7}.compact
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, it works very well. It isn't homework though, I work with genome sequencing and those are quality values. I asked in Ruby because my coworker knows it a bit better. I've asked other questions regarding sequencing analysis. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
num_string = "7  3  5  7  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  6  7  5  5 22 1 4 23 16 18 5  13 34 24 17 50 30 42 35 29 27 52 35 44 52 36 39 25 40 50 52 40 2 52 52 31 35 30 19 32 46 50 43 36 15 21 16 36 25 7  3  5  17  3  3  3  3  23  3  3  46 1 2"

num_arr = num_string.split(" ")


def next_ones(arr)
    counter = 0
    arr.each do |num|
        if num.to_i > 10
            counter += 1
        end
    end
    if counter >= 7
        arr[0]
    end
end

def processor(arr)
    answer = []
    arr.each_with_index do |num, index|
        if num.to_i > 10
            answer << next_ones(arr[index...(index + 15)])
        end
    end
    answer.compact.join(" ")
end

processor(num_arr)
```

A bit verbose, and with bad naming, but it should give you some ideas.